# Using u-subsitution to integrate $ \int_{0}^{1} e^{3 x^{3}-2 x}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) d x $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

**Question**: Use the u-subsitution to integrate $ \int_{0}^{1} e^{3 x^{3}-2 x}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) d x $

---

So far my working is as follows

\begin{equation}
u=3 x^{3}-2 x \Longrightarrow \frac{d u}{d x}=9 x^{2}-2
\end{equation}
Step two:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d u}=\frac{1}{9 x^{2}-2}
\end{equation}

Substituting u in

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{u}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) d x
\end{equation}

For definite integration using substitution what changes occur as compared to indefinite u substitution?

EDIT:

After looking at this question I believe I am close to the answer

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{4}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) \frac{1}{9 x^{2}-2} d x
\end{equation}

Canceling them out we get;

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{u} d u
\end{equation}

when x=1, our new limit is 7 when x=0 our new limit is -2

Comment: Noted @AdamRubinson thank you

Comment: You can just use $du=(9x^2-2)dx$.

Comment: You have not "substituted $u$ in", your expression is a mixture of $u$s and $x$s.

Comment: Now substitute $(9x^2-2)\cdot dx $ by $du.$ And don't forget to adjust the boundaries of integration, too.

Comment: So du=(9x^2-2) I can replace du with that expression and then write dx at the end

Comment: So for this I wrote the integral and then cancelled out \begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{u}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) \frac{1}{9 x^{2}-2} d u
\end{equation}  like so \begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{u} d u
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

\begin{equation}
\frac{d x}{d u}=\frac{1}{9 x^{2}-2},
\end{equation}

We are allowed to multiply both sides by $du$ to get:

\begin{equation}
d x=\frac{1}{9 x^{2}-2} du.
\end{equation}

Substitute this into \begin{equation}
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} e^{u}\left(9 x^{2}-2\right) d x.
\end{equation}

But then you must get the limits $x=1$ and $x=0$ also in terms of $u.$

So you have to replace $x=1$ with $u=?$ [What is $u$ when $x=1$?]

And similar for $x=0.$

Only once everything is in terms of $u$ are you allowed to evaluate the integral.

Comment: So when x=1 I have \begin{equation}
e^{u}
\end{equation} multiplied by 7 and \begin{equation}
e^{u}
\end{equation} multiplied by -2

Comment: I've got it I think when x=1 u=7 when x=0 u=-2

Comment: Just to note - it is **really** helpful to use @Adam Rubinson's notation here, in order to not get confused on where your limits of integration are.  Adam has noted the variable name in his limits of integration, and I would **strongly** encourage this behavior anytime you are doing $u$-substitution, as it prevents many errors.

Comment: So write out the integral again but with new limits?

Comment: @johnnyb from the notation showed how would you get it to respect to u? Would you need to get x on its own? I feel like having the reciprocal dx/du and then cancelling makes it easier?

Comment: In this case, they are (surprisingly) actually the same.  You can use the equation you came up with for $u$ to make the transition.  You said, $u = 3x^3 - 2x$.  For $x = 0$, this makes $u = 0$.  For $x = 1$ this makes $u = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression after u-substitution is just $$\int_0^1 e^u du=e^{3x^2-2x}\Bigg |^1_0$$ You can do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspection you can write
$$
\int_0^1e^{3x^3-2x}(9x^2-2)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1e^{3x^3-2x}\,\mathrm d(3x^3-2x).
$$
Since we are now integrating with respect to the quantity in the exponent, the result follows immediately
$$
\int_0^1e^{3x^3-2x}\,\mathrm d(3x^3-2x)=e^{3x^3-2x}|_{x=0}^1=e-1.
$$
Admittedly, this is just $u$-substitution in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

So from my workings I computed

\begin{equation}
\left(e^{u}\right)_{0}^{1}=e^{1}-e^{0}=e-1
\end{equation}

This is from

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{u} d u
\end{equation}

Therefore giving our final answer

\begin{equation}
\left(e^{u}\right)_{0}^{1}=e^{1}-e^{0}=e-1
\end{equation}

Comment: Good job! you got it.

Comment: Thank you for the clue, it was much easier than I thought it would be

Comment: doing my job :)